# How to put a delete button under each post in my blog/website?

Tags: php

I am wanting to put a delete button, so people  can delete their post if they want on my simple blog website. I am just a little unsure how to do it. I guess I need to put a value=delete input field on my posting_wall but not sure where to go from there. Thank you in advnace if you can help me.

Form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/footer.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/header.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 150 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[-\.a-zA-Z\s0-9]{3,150}$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Sorry, only alphanumerical characters are allowed and 3-150 character limit".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // "name" pattern : at least 1 digit

    value = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/\d+/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "name".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php include 'header.php' ?>

<form action="posting_wall.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="20" required><br>
Post:<br>

<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name='message'></textarea>
</div>

Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" > <br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p><a href="posting_wall.php">Posting Wall</a></p>
<div id="time">
<?php 

$nextWeek = time() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60);
// 7 days; 24 hours; 60 mins; 60secs
echo 'The time at which you are posting is:'. date('h:i Y-m-d') ."\n";
?>
</div>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Posting Wall Page (where I want the delete button under each post)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/post.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/footer.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Daily Dorm News <br></h1>
<h2> Your Daily Dorm News Posts </h2>
<div id="container"> <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php if ( isset($_GET['message']) and preg_match("/^[-\.a-zA-Z\s0-9]+$/", $_GET['message']) ) {

    echo $_GET['message'];

} else {

    echo "The message is not valid! The message box was blank or you entered invalid symbols!\n";

}
?>
<br>
This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>


</div>

<?php
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
* Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
*/

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);
$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
 // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  

 // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
 $post_fields = array();
 $post_fields['name'] = $name;
 $post_fields['email'] = $email;
 $post_fields['message'] = $message;
 $post_fields['date'] = $date;
 $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);

}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

?>

 <?php
   if(isset($name)) {
     echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
   }
   ?>




<p id="received">Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
<div id="logo">Dont Forget to tell you’re friends about Daily Dorm Post! <br>
The only Dorm News Website on campus!</div>
<ul id="posts_list">
   <?php

   // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
   $counter = 1;

   foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
    $alreadyPosted = false;
     $name = $post['name'];
     $email = $post['email'];
     $message = $post['message'];
     $date = $post['date'];

     if ($counter % 2==1)
       $li_class = "float-left";
     else
       $li_class = "float-right";

     if ($name == $_GET['name']) {
        $alreadyPosted = true;
     }
        echo '<div class=post';
          if ($alreadyPosted) {
            echo ' id="highlight"';
          }
        echo '>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
        echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This event occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';
        echo '</div>';
   }
   ?>

</ul>
</div>
<p id="submit"><a href="../index.php">Would you like to submit another post?</a></p>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a delete button or make `<a href=""></a>`

```
<script>
function confirm(){
var responce = confirm("Are you sure want to delete?");
if (responce==true)
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  return false;
} 

}

</script>

<a onclick="confirm()" href="delete_post.php?id=1>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Yes and also make the delete_post.php